# Reading a record in a file which is split on multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, file-io

```
ID|Text 1|Date|Text2
1|Hello There
what a wonderful day|12th|Out in the market
2|Well I wish|13th|Sleeping
3|It is rocking, python
is a great language
to code|18th|what to do
in this scenario
4|Text issues|19th|Solving
```

So I have the text in above format in a file where I want to read each record line by line however there is a problem that there are new lines within a record that does not make me iterate using 'for line in file:' idiom. My problem is that I have to read all the above records, a record a time.

Example of a record from above file: "1, Hello There what a wonderful day, 12th, Out in the market"

I was thinking of using regexes here after reading all of the file in memory. So for example, having a regex like `(\d*|)(.*)(\d*|)` will allow me to get everything between 2 ID's and that becomes my one record.

The problem that I have with the above approach is that how do I need to go to the next record and start matching again?

I am unable to think of a pattern in the above which will help me solve my problem. To reiterate I can't read line by line as the lines in records itself are splitted with new lines.

Another way of stating the problem would be as to how to format the file in a way that new lines are removed for each record and each records gets properly formatted line by line.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: How large is your file? You may read the whole file and change your regex to match fields with multiple lines.

Comment: My file is not large, it will fit into memory.

Comment: This looks like unescaped csv text fields. Can the pipe symbol occur in the text fields?

Answer (score 0):

Old school solution: use `csv` module, accumulating row size & concatenating until size is the same as title size.

```
import csv

rows = []
prev_row = None
with open("foo.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    title = next(cr)
    rows.append(title)
    for row in cr:
        if prev_row:
            prev_row[-1]+="\n"+row[0]
            prev_row+=row[1:]
        else:
            prev_row = row

        if len(prev_row)==len(title):
            rows.append(prev_row)
            prev_row = []

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

rows print as

```
['ID', 'Text 1', 'Date', 'Text2']
['1', 'Hello There\nwhat a wonderful day', '12th', 'Out in the market']
['2', 'Well I wish', '13th', 'Sleeping']
['3', 'It is rocking, python\nis a great language\nto code', '18th', 'what to do']
['in this scenario\n4', 'Text issues', '19th', 'Solving']
```